# how to convert string to dict with double quotes in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to convert string to dict with double quotes

here is example

```py
"{'a':'b'}"
```

i tried replace with json.dumps
but it is not resolved

```py
a = "{'a':'b'}"
b = a.replace("'", "\"") # '{"id":"b"}'
c = json.dumps(c, ensure_ascii=False) # '"{\"id\\":\"b\"}"'
```

i want to solve like this

```py
{"a":"b"}
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Use the parser corresponding to the formatter you used to produce that string in the first place. We don't know what you used, only you do.

Comment: I think you meant `loads` instead of `dumps`

Comment: that's not JSON, which requires double quotes, but it looks a lot like python. `ast.literal_eval`. Please post a running example of your first attempt so that we can make changes to it.

Comment: Where did that string come from? What sort of encoding rules does it follow? Its easy to decode that string but who knows if other similar strings would also decode.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has left replies. Looking back at the question I wrote, I found that the explanation was too short. The problem was solved by referring to the answers you left below. Next time I'll put a little more context and leave a question. Thanks again for learning how to ask questions.
thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not JSON.

```
>>> import json
>>> foo = "{'a':'b'}"
>>> json.loads(foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

But it does look a lot like python

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(foo)
{'a': 'b'}
```

Whether this works for you depends on where this string came from and what its serialization rules are.

Comment: I solved the problem by applying this answer. Thank you

Comment: what if there was a `nested_dictionary`?

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh - This would work for [python literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) like strings, integers, dictionaries, etc... So, nested `dict` with these types would be fine. But if you have a class called `nested_dictionary`, then its a no-go.

Comment: How come this answer is accepted, the OP literally asked for the conversion to double quoted string and not with the single string???

Comment: @comrade49 - Because the conversion to double quoted strings wasn't the proper solution. OP doesn't tell us the string format, leaving us to guess. I was very clear that this was a provisional answer - if this is a python literal, then use python. You can't just replace the single quotes in the general case because the string itself may have internal quotes that would not be properly replaced. Replacing the quotes would just be a hack that doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps` takes a structure and dumps it as JSON.  You want `json.loads`, which takes a JSON string and loads it into a structure.

```
>>> json.loads(a.replace("'", '"'))
{'a': 'b'}
```

Comment: What if one of the strings contains a double quote?

Comment: You'll get an error from `json.loads`, probably.

Comment: Or a corrupted string. Point is, this is likely not a good way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the single quotes in `a`, it's more likely a Python dict than a JSON object, so you probably want [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = "{'a':'b'}"
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
{'a': 'b'}
```